# Gulp watch task with Browsersync with Jekyll does not propagate modified content

Tags: javascript, gulp, jekyll, browser-sync, gulp-watch

When calling `gulp` the site and its assets are generated correctly once. The watch tasks start, but they never register new changes nor refresh the browser with Browsersync.

My goal is to have a full automation in the build process. For example, if `_config.yml` changes Jekyll will rebuild itself. Same idea applies to every file.

What I have tried so far:

1. Creating separate `gulp.watch` tasks for `build:scripts`, `build:styles`, `build:images` and `build:jekyll`.
2. Calling `.on('change', browserSync.reload)` on every separate `gulp.watch` task
3. Creating `.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))` in `build:styles`, `build:images`, `build:scripts` and `build:jekyll`

Here are the contents of `gulpfile.js`:

```
'use strict';

var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();
var concat       = require('gulp-concat');
var del          = require('del');
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin');
var rename       = require('gulp-rename');
var run          = require('gulp-run');
var runSequence  = require('run-sequence');
var sass         = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify       = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('build:styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('_assets/styles/main.sass')
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ 
            browsers: ['last 4 versions'] 
        }))
        .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/styles'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('build:scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('_assets/js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('build:images', function() {
    return gulp.src('_assets/img')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/img'));
});

gulp.task('build:jekyll', function(callback) {
    // --incremental regeneration doesn't update front matter
    var shellCommand = 'jekyll build';

    return gulp.src('')
        .pipe(run(shellCommand))

    browserSync.reload();
    callback();
});


gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del(['_site', 'assets']);
});

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
    return runSequence('clean', ['build:scripts', 'build:styles', 'build:images'], 'build:jekyll', callback)
});

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: '_site'
        },
        open: true
    });

    gulp.watch(['_config.yml' , 
                '*.html', '_layouts/*.*', 
                '_pages/*.*', '_assets/**/**/*.*'], 
                ['build']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Why would Browsersync and Jekyll register the changes correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get Browsersync see all the changes in the needed files and reload browser with the following `gulpfile.js` tasks:

```
'use strict';

var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();
var concat       = require('gulp-concat');
var del          = require('del');
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin');
var rename       = require('gulp-rename');
var run          = require('gulp-run');
var runSequence  = require('run-sequence');
var sass         = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify       = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del(['_site', '.publish', 'assets']);
});

gulp.task('build:scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('_assets/js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'));
});

gulp.task('build:styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('_assets/styles/main.sass')
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ 
            browsers: ['last 4 versions'] 
        }))
        .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/styles'));
});

gulp.task('build:images', function() {
    return gulp.src('_assets/img')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/img'));
});

gulp.task('build:jekyll', function(callback) {
    // --incremental regeneration doesn't update front matter
    var shellCommand = 'jekyll build';

    return gulp.src('')
        .pipe(run(shellCommand));

    callback();
});

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
    return runSequence('clean', ['build:scripts', 'build:styles', 'build:images'], 'build:jekyll', callback)
});

gulp.task('rebuild', ['build'], function(){
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('default', ['build'], function() {

    // maybe important (injectChanges: true)
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: '_site'
        },
        open: true
    });

    gulp.watch(['_config.yml' , 
                '*.html', '_layouts/*.*', 
                '_pages/*.*', '_assets/**/**/*.*'], 
                ['rebuild']);
});
```